# Is the derivative of an algebraic function algebraic? (Solved)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-algebra

I'm studying Liouville's theory of elementary integration and I came across an unproven fact that the derivative of an algebraic function is algebraic. I can see this intuitively, but I can't rigorously prove it using the algebraic function definition.

A function y is algebraic if it satisfies an equation of the form

$$P_ny^n+P_{n-1}y^{n-1}+\cdots+P_1y+P_0=0,$$
where each $P_1,\ldots,P_n$ is a polynomial.

I tried to differentiate this equation and found

$$P'_ny^n+nP_ny^{n-1}y'+P'_{n-1}y^{n-1}+(n-1)P_{n-1}y^{n-2}y'+\cdots+P'_1y+P_1y'+P_0'=0,$$
but I can't manipulate this equation to find an algebraic equation involving just $y'$. If anyone has a tip or solution for this I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Is the sum of algebraic functions algebraic ?

Comment: Can you show that algebraic functions from a field? If so, you can solve your last equality for $y'$ and the result will be algebraic.

Comment: To add on @SangchulLee $\Bbb{C}(z)[y]$ is a field and a finite dimensional $\Bbb{C}(z)$ vector space so all its elements are such that $\Bbb{C}(z)[a]$ is a finite dimensional $\Bbb{C}(z)$-vector space ie. they are algebraic over $\Bbb{C}(z)$. In particular this holds for $a=y'$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I'll look at it.

Comment: @SangchulLee I think I got it! I found a book on algebraic and transcendental numbers and it proves that the set of algebraic numbers forms a field. I adapted the proof to the context of algebraic functions and it worked. With this I isolate $y'$ and as it will result in the quotient of two algebraic functions, it will be algebraic.